# Can I put two dependent sentences into one subordinating conjunction?

Tags: grammar

Can I put two sentences into one subordinating conjunction?

Example,

> > (1) **After I finished doing my homework and my mom came home**, we went out for dinner.
> >
> > (2) **After I finished doing my homework and after my mom came home**, we went out for dinner.

I know the second one is grammatically correct, but is the first one also grammatically correct?

Comment: yes, the first sentence is OK too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct:

> After I finished doing my homework and my mom came home, we went out for dinner.